# Reactjs render and state change dependancies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS at the moment and struggling to understand how to render/update content based on changes elsewhere.

Example:

I have a timer app, which includes pause/restart functionality. It contains a Start/Pause button.

**Timer.js**

```
export class Timer {
  constructor(parentApp) {
    this.app = app;
    this.playing = false;
  }
  start() {
    this.playing = true;
  }
  pause() {
    this.playing = false;
  }
}
```

**Button.js**

```
export class IconButtonBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {label: 'Start'};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="IconButtonBar">
        <Button label={this.state.label} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to update the label:

- Depending whether the timer is started/stopped at initial render
- When the timer is manually started/stopped by pressing the button
- When the timer is manually started/stopped by another means
- When the timer is programatically started/stopped (e.g. limit reached)

In jQuery I'd probably fire a custom event trgger to the body tag:

```
$('body').on('start_playing', function() {
  $('#playpause_button).text('Pause');
}
```

But there are probably much more 'native' ways to do this in ReactJS.

I hope this makes sense, and you can help!

Comment: You could store the label in `Timer` component state and pass down the label to the `IconButtonBar` as a prop and use that. e.g. `this.props.label`. You could then update the `label` in the state depending on if a limit was reached, the start button was pressed, etc.

Comment: I was going to give a similar idea. Pass the playing state to button component and conditionally change the label string. But passing a prop prevents this conditional logic. Please let me ask a question @Tholle, keeping the label state in the Timer can be an "anti-pattern" here? I'm ok with this I just want to learn as a learner.

Comment: I don't think it's an anti-pattern. [Lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the first common ancestor is most likely the way to go here. Trying to have a lot of logic inside the `IconButtonBar` component to choose the appropriate label would probably be very hard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Thinking again, yes you are right @Tholle. The logic would be very messy in the button component. But, lifting the state part confuses me. If any other component does not use this `label` state then do we need to lift the state? But again, a messy logic is probably worse then passing the label here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your vision of how react app is structurized. Just forget about jQuery. React is declarative, you need to say it what should be rendered (surely it can be done another way, but why to use React then?).

You can use stateful component if you have no third-party store library.

You can use conditional redering for showing different elements depending on different state.

Here is an example stateful component of what you wanted to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/14vokm9q14

Just remember, it is not a good practice to keep state in a view layer. Consider using Redux/Mobx:

- Redux - it will require a lot of boilerplate: creation of reducers, action-creators, action-types, handling side-effects (with redux-thunk/redux-saga/redux-observable), etc. But it is stable, reliable and easy-testable.
- Mobx - something like you have in your example. It is MVVM, where you have model in its classical meaning, decorate properties as observable and just inject this model into your react component. After that you can just mutate properties of your model and these changes will reflect onto your view.